# sklearn, how to change array in proper dimension

Tags: python, scikit-learn

i am doing project using sklearn, and I have a problem with multi-dimensional array and inproper index. It's my first project with Python (sorry)
Here is code :

```
for classifier, classifier_name in classifiers:
    feature_results = []
    for feature in feature_numbers:
        features = [x[0] for x in best_features[:feature]]
        train_selected_features = X[:,features]
        rskf = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, n_repeats=5)
        scores = []
        for train_index, test_index in rskf.split(train_selected_features, Y):
            X_train, X_test = train_selected_features[train_index], train_selected_features[test_index]
            y_train, y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
            test = train_selected_features[X_train]

            classifier.fit(train_selected_features[X_train], Y[y_train])

            scores.append(classifier.score(train_selected_features[X_test], Y[y_test]))
```

And I'm getting 2 errors. First `ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.`

In line
 `classifier.fit(train_selected_features[X_train], Y[y_train])`

And second `IndexError: index 20 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 20`

in line 
`train_selected_features = X[:,features]`

Data:

```
classifiers = [
(MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(20,), activation='relu'), 'MLP_20__relu'),
(MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(100,), activation='relu'), 'MLP_100_relu'),
(MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(200,), activation='relu'), 'MLP_200_relu'),
(MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(20,),activation='identity' ), 'MLP_20_identity'),
(MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(100,), activation='identity'), 'MLP_100_identity'),
(MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(200,), activation='identity'), 'MLP_200_identity'),]
```

best_features (order of  features after features selection)
    `[(4, 112.95204710846082), (17, 61.046858861185996), (19, 55.064337711834064), (2, 52.168346298312485), (14, 50.004023585296), (18, 41.96290891060357), (12, 19.59769266560766), (15, 14.883924792279542), (6, 11.920742454442108), (10, 11.062850868379167), (13, 10.667800318033635), (20, 10.667800318033635), (11, 8.301076254737337), (5, 8.078569220877426), (7, 8.003708818567706), (16, 7.794623436938262), (9, 7.077799520283073), (8, 5.867933581615914), (3, 3.735103501864392), (1, 1.7623125985633417)]`

X 
`[[2 1 1 ... 1 1 1]
 [2 1 1 ... 2 4 1]
 [2 2 1 ... 1 2 1]
 ...
 [2 1 1 ... 1 1 2]
 [2 3 1 ... 1 1 1]
 [1 3 1 ... 2 2 2]]`

x[0]
`[2 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1]`

Y

`[ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3
  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  4  4
  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6
  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7
  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8
  8  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9
  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11 11
 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 12 12 12 12 12
 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13
 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14
 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15
 15 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 17 17
 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18
 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19
 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
 20 20]`

feature_numbers
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]`

Thank you.

Comment: Please, try to improve formatting.

Comment: Is the data type numpy.array?

Comment: I don't use numpy in this part of code, i use pandas

Comment: you have a lot of of problems. If you do `X = np.array(X)` and then `X.shape` what do you get?

Comment: after this i get (410, 20)

Comment: @ulaniec97 , if you want to search for the best parameters don't use this way which makes your code dirty. Look for `Gridsearch sklearn` or `hyperopt` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
import numpy as np

# build artificial X
x=[2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,2 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1]
X=[x for i in range(410)]
X = np.array(X)
X.shape
#(410, 20)

best_features = [(4, 112.95204710846082),
                 (17, 61.046858861185996),
                 (19, 55.064337711834064),
                 (2, 52.168346298312485),
                 (14, 50.004023585296),
                 (18, 41.96290891060357),
                 (12, 19.59769266560766),
                 (15, 14.883924792279542),
                 (6, 11.920742454442108),
                 (10, 11.062850868379167),
                 (13, 10.667800318033635),
                 (20, 10.667800318033635),
                 (11, 8.301076254737337),
                 (5, 8.078569220877426),
                 (7, 8.003708818567706),
                 (16, 7.794623436938262),
                 (9, 7.077799520283073),
                 (8, 5.867933581615914),
                 (3, 3.735103501864392),
                 (1, 1.7623125985633417)]

feature_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

classifiers = [
(MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(20,), activation='relu'), 'MLP_20__relu'),
(MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(100,), activation='relu'), 'MLP_100_relu'),
(MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(200,), activation='relu'), 'MLP_200_relu'),
(MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(20,),activation='identity' ), 'MLP_20_identity'),
(MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(100,), activation='identity'), 'MLP_100_identity'),
(MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(200,), activation='identity'), 'MLP_200_identity')]

# artificial Y
Y = np.arange(1,21)
Y = np.repeat(Y,21)
Y = Y[:410]

for classifier, classifier_name in classifiers:
    feature_results = []
    for feature in feature_numbers:
        features = [x[0] for x in best_features[:feature]]
        features = [i-1 for i in features]
        train_selected_features = X[:,features]
        rskf = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, n_repeats=5)
        scores = []
        for train_index, test_index in rskf.split(train_selected_features, Y):
            X_train, X_test = train_selected_features[train_index], train_selected_features[test_index]
            y_train, y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
            test = train_selected_features[X_train]
            classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
            scores.append(classifier.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: ok, now I have the same error but in next line classifier.fit(train_selected_features[X_train], Y[y_train])

Comment: I get (410, 20)

Comment: error ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2 in line classifier.fit(train_selected_features[X_train], Y[y_train])

Comment: Now the code should work fine. Consider accepting and upvoting my answer. cheers

Comment: last error sorry,  in line scores.append(classifier.score(train_selected_features[X_test], Y[y_test])) error ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2. That works scores.append(classifier.score(X_test, y_test)) thx

Comment: fixed. upvote, accept and please read the documentation more carefully next time. You split the data and then you do not use `X_test ` etc. see my updated code